# Load a table from wikipedia into R

Tags: xml, r, html-parsing, data.table

I'm trying to load the table of Supreme Court Justices into R from the following URL.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States

I'm using the following code:

```
scotusURL <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States"
scotusData <- getURL(scotusURL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
scotusDoc <- htmlParse(scotusData)
scotusData <- scotusDoc['//table[@class="wikitable"]']
scotusTable <- readHTMLTable(scotusData[[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

R returns scotusTable as NULL. The goal here is to get a data.frame in R that I can use to make a ggplot of SCOTUS justice tenure on the Court. I previously had the script working to make an awesome plot, however after the recent decisions something changed on the page and now the script will not function. I went through the HTML on wikipedia to try to find any changes, however I'm not a webdev so anything that would break my script isn't immediately apparent.

Additionally, is there a method in R that would allow me to cache the data from this page so I'm not constantly referencing the URL? That would seem to be the ideal way to avoid this issue in the future.
Appreciate the help.

As an aside, SCOTUS in an on-going hobby/side-project of mine so if there's some other data source out there that's better than wikipedia, I'm all ears.

Edit: Sorry I should have listed my dependencies. I'm using the XML, plyr, RCurl, data.table, and ggplot2 libraries.

Comment: What is the source of `getURL` function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843659/scraping-a-complex-html-table-into-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Regarding your aside, you might consider asking on the open data stackexchange site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't mind using a different package, you can try the "rvest" package.

```
library(rvest)    
scotusURL <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States"
```

- Option 1: Grab the tables from the page and use the `html_table` function to extract the tables you're interested in.

  ```
  temp <- scotusURL %>% 
    html %>%
    html_nodes("table")

  html_table(temp[1]) ## Just the "legend" table
  html_table(temp[2]) ## The table you're interested in
  ```
- Option 2: Inspect the table element and copy the XPath to read that table directly (right-click, inspect element, scroll to the relevant "table" tag, right click on that, and select "Copy XPath").

  ```
  scotusURL %>% 
    html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]') %>% 
    html_table
  ```

---

Another option I like is loading the data in a Google spreadsheet and reading it using the ["googlesheets" package](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets).

In Google Drive, create a new spreadsheet named, for instance "Supreme Court". In the first worksheet, enter:

```
=importhtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States", "table", 2)
```

This will automatically scrape this table into your Google spreadsheet.

From there, in R you can do:

```
library(googlesheets)
SC <- gs_title("Supreme Court")
gs_read(SC)
```

Comment: `temp = tempfile(); httr::GET(wurl, user_agent("Dogzilla"), write_disk(temp)); tables <- XML::readHTMLTable(temp); tables[[2]]; ` gives me the same table as above code does, but how do you clean the years etc. Those comes out as jumbled.  Like born/died for the first row comes out as `174512121745–1829` while actually it is `1745–1829`. No idea where the extra characters come from.

Comment: @Frash, I don't know exactly *how* this happens, but it appears to be a precise date (12/12/1745) embedded in the final year value.

Comment: You are right, the wiki page shows that date in edit mode.

Comment: You need to remove the `<span style=display:none>` nodes to avoid the extra judge names and dates.  I added an answer to do this in XML but would like to see how to do this in rvest

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States"
library(rvest) #v 0.2.0.9000
the_table <- read_html(url) %>% html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(11)") %>% html_table()
```

Comment: If you have an older version of the `rvest` package, you may need to replace `read_html(url)` with `html(url)` .

Answer (score 1):

I would remove all the `<span style="display:none">` nodes and read the table from scotusDoc instead of trying to select a table class value that has changed.

```
scotusDoc <- htmlParse(scotusData, encoding="UTF-8")
xpathSApply(scotusDoc, "//span[@style='display:none']", removeNodes)
x <- readHTMLTable(scotusDoc, which=2,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

head(x)
  #           Judge State Born/Died         Active service Chief Justice Retirement Appointed by Reason for\ntermination
1 1       John Jay†    NY 1745–1829   1789–1795(5–6 years)     1789–1795          —   Washington             Resignation
2 2   John Rutledge    SC 1739–1800   1789–1791(1–2 years)             —          —   Washington        Resignation[n 1]
3 3 William Cushing    MA 1732–1810 1789–1810(20–21 years)             —          —   Washington                   Death
4 4    James Wilson    PA 1742–1798   1789–1798(8–9 years)             —          —   Washington                   Death
5 5 John Blair, Jr.    VA 1732–1800   1789–1795(5–6 years)             —          —   Washington             Resignation
6 6   James Iredell    NC 1751–1799   1790–1799(8–9 years)             —          —   Washington                   Death
```

And here are table classes, so the second table is now a "wikitable sortable"

```
xpathSApply(scotusDoc, "//table", xmlGetAttr, "class")
[1] "wikitable"                                         "wikitable sortable"                               
[3] "navbox"                                            "nowraplinks collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner"
[5] "navbox"                                            "nowraplinks collapsible collapsed navbox-inner
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the googlesheets dependency wasn't working, so I pulled it through google anyway.

I ran:

```
=importhtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States", "table", 2)
```

and then downloaded the file as a .csv

Don't know why I didn't think of that before. I'll have to re-write my string scripts to clean it up but this ended up being the best way to 1) fix the first problem I had and 2) download a file so that I don't have to keep referencing a URL.

Thanks for the help.