# How to scrape data from all tables of this website using R?

Tags: r, rvest

I need to extract all data from all tables from this website in http://ncpscxx.moa.gov.cn/#/sing?headingIndex=true&item=1 but I didn´t have success...

I tryed with rvest but...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://ncpscxx.moa.gov.cn/#/sing?headingIndex=true&item=1"

page <- read_html(url)

tables<- page %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) 

View(tables) # There is a null list :(
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried looking for posts about scraping tables in R? You will likely have to find the specific XPath if there are multiple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944527/reading-in-a-table-using-rvest/72944693#72944693  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176709/load-a-table-from-wikipedia-into-r/31177077#31177077 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310595/data-scraping-in-r/50382537#50382537

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the screen is not HTML. You can use packages like "httr2" or "httr" to request the data from various links gathered from `network` section. Which can be found in the developer tools.

This is an example for the dataset in the bottom right.

```
"http://ncpscxx.moa.gov.cn/product/livestock-product-feed/trend/count" %>%  
  request() %>% 
  req_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63") %>% 
  req_body_json(list(
    varietyCode = "AL01001", 
    queryEndTime = "2020", 
    queryStartTime = "2011"
  )) %>%  
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%  
  getElement(4) %>%  
  as_tibble

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  AMOUNT_FEED CHANGE_RATE REPORT_TIME
        <int> <chr>       <chr>      
1        8612 -           2014<U+5E74>     
2        7949 -7.7        2015<U+5E74>     
3        8298 4.39        2016<U+5E74>     
4        9078 9.4         2017<U+5E74>     
5        9584 5.57        2018<U+5E74>     
6        7651 -20.17      2019<U+5E74>     
7        8874 15.98       2020<U+5E74>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Hoel ! But how can I change your code example here to get other tables ?

Comment: @RodrigoH.Ozon You need to inspect the network tab in the developer tools to gather the links for each tables. Unfornunately, I wont be doing that as one example should be sufficient. Learn more about `httr2` here: https://httr2.r-lib.org/

Comment: I´m not the best html knower, but I tryed to find the same link that you have used in example and I didn´t have success to find....I´ll keep continue trying! Thks a lot @Tom Hoel!