# Removing Span tag in R; data appearing twice

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract data from a html page in R with the code below:

```
wiki_url_html <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_players_suspended_for_performance-enhancing_drugs")

bb_player_PED <- (wiki_url_html %>% 
html_nodes(xpath = '//table[3]') %>% html_table())[[1]]

head(bb_player_PED, 10)
```

gives me the data below:

```
Player                 Team                           Date announced       Drug      Penalty Position
1              Sánchez, AlexAlex Sánchez Tampa Bay Devil Rays     000000002005-04-03-0000April 3, 2005            010 !10 days       OF
2        Montero, AgustínAgustín Montero        Texas Rangers    000000002005-04-20-0000April 20, 2005            010 !10 days        P
3              Strong, JamalJamal Strong     Seattle Mariners    000000002005-04-26-0000April 26, 2005            010 !10 days       OF
4                Rincón, JuanJuan Rincón      Minnesota Twins       000000002005-05-02-0000May 2, 2005            010 !10 days        P
5    Betancourt, RafaelRafael Betancourt    Cleveland Indians      000000002005-07-08-0000July 8, 2005            010 !10 days        P
6  Palmeiro, RafaelRafael Palmeiro SS GG    Baltimore Orioles    000000002005-08-01-0000August 1, 2005 Stanozolol 010 !10 days       DH
7            Franklin, RyanRyan Franklin     Seattle Mariners    000000002005-08-02-0000August 2, 2005            010 !10 days        P
8                  Morse, MikeMike Morse     Seattle Mariners 000000002005-09-07-0000September 7, 2005            010 !10 days       SS
9        Almanzar, CarlosCarlos Almanzar        Texas Rangers   000000002005-10-04-0000October 4, 2005            010 !10 days        P
10           Heredia, FélixFélix Heredia        New York Mets  000000002005-10-18-0000October 18, 2005            010 !10 days        P
Response Ref.
1       [a]  [5]
2       [b]  [7]
3       [c]  [9]
4       [d]  [9]
5       [e] [12]
6       [f] [14]
7       [g] [16]
8       [h] [18]
9       [i] [20]
10      [j] [22]
```

my question is how to remove the span tag from the data so that certain data don't appear twice in the columns like Player, Date Announced, Penalty?

I understand that it s because the table has span tags and using the code above concatenates the span tag's data.

I tried the following:

```
removeNodes(getNodeSet(xmlTreeParse(wiki_url_html, useInternalNodes = T), "//table/tr/th/i/span"))
```

like from the stack overflow post:

[Scraping a complex HTML table into a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843659/scraping-a-complex-html-table-into-a-data-frame-in-r/40823563?noredirect=1#comment68865894_40823563)

to remove the span tags but it just returns NULL.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.