# Scrape a table from a non-HTML website with R yet examples shown are for HTML

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have an issue. I am trying to scrape the two tables from a non-html website.
This is the website:

https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/web_site_content/supporting_information/main_specialty_and_treatment_function_codes_table.asp

Yet, I am following something I should not but do not find any answer. This is what I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(httr)



url <- "https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/web_site_content/supporting_information/main_specialty_and_treatment_function_codes_table.asp"

poptable <- readHTMLTable(url, which = 1)
```

And get this error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
> In addition: Warning message: XML content does not seem to be XML:
> 'https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/web_site_content/supporting_information/main_specialty_and_treatment_function_codes_table.asp'

I thought regardless of the asp website type, I still can use the function readHTMLTable. Is there any alternative to this. I haven't found any yet and struggled for hours to get something out.

Comment: It isn't a "non-HTML" site. Maybe the HTML is rendered dynamically, in which case there are tools like Selenium that can help and are documented in other SO questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that's pretty straightfoward (based on [@lukeA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844317/11129727)):

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/web_site_content/supporting_information/main_specialty_and_treatment_function_codes_table.asp"

page <- read_html(url)
nodes <- html_nodes(page, "table") # you can use Selectorgadget to identify the node
table <- html_table(nodes[[1]]) # each element of the nodes list is one table that can be extracted
head(table)
                                       Code  Main Specialty Title
1 Surgical Specialties Surgical Specialties  Surgical Specialties
2                                       100       GENERAL SURGERY
3                                       101               UROLOGY
4                                       110 TRAUMA & ORTHOPAEDICS
5                                       120                   ENT
6                                       130         OPHTHALMOLOGY
```

Selectorgadget can be installed here: [Selectorgadget by Hadley Wickham](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html)

Comment: I see, it worked. Thank you. I haven't found any previous issues. Yet it was there. Can you pleas help, is the asp website a html? Because lukeA's answer shows it for an html table. What is the difference?

Comment: I guest that all websites are html-pages with various elements. The tricky part is to identify the "names" those elements that you are interested in. That's what you can use the Selectorgadget for. With Selectorgadget I figured out that the relevant tables are "table" nodes and that's what I put into the `html_nodes` command. If you are not interested in tables, you might use `html_text` instead of `html_table` in the next step.